# how can i store several rdf data to a tdb dataset?

Tags: model, dataset, store, rdf, jena

i am complete newer to tdb and i want to store several rdf data into tdb .many code is as follows:

```
public static final String book = "Ontologies/book.rdf";
public static final String conference = "Ontologies/conference.rdf";
public static final String inproceeding = "Ontologies/inproceeding.rdf";
public static final String journal = "Ontologies/journal.rdf";
public static final String JournalArtical = "Ontologies/JournalArtical.rdf";
public static final String organization = "Ontologies/organization.rdf";
public static final String person = "Ontologies/person.rdf";
public static final String place = "Ontologies/place.rdf";
public static final String proceedings = "Ontologies/proceedings.rdf";
public static final String series = "Ontologies/series.rdf";
public static final String thesis = "Ontologies/thesis.rdf";

static String queryRequest = "select * {?s ?p ?o.}";

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList();
   // al.add(book);
    al.add(conference);
   al.add(inproceeding);
    al.add(journal);
   al.add(JournalArtical);
    al.add(organization);
    al.add(person);
   al.add(place);
   al.add(proceedings);
    al.add(series);
   al.add(thesis);

    //create the DataSet   
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("QA");
    Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
    //to fill model  
    Iterator  it=  al.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
    FileManager.get().readModel(model, (String)it.next());
    }

    model.commit();
    dataset.close();
}
}
```

it throws a ConcurrentModificationException Exception ?
i don't know why ?
can a model store many rdf data?

Comment: where does it throw ConcurrentModificationException? (which version is this?).

Comment: The exception throwed are as follows:Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: Iterator: started at 208, now 209,--------at this line: FileManager.get().readModel(model, (String)it.next());   and  my tdb vrsion is TDB-0.8.10;

Answer (score 0):

TDB does a lot of async stuff, so you could try adding `TDB.sync(model)` after each read operation to force it to wait for the operation to be truly complete before moving on to the next one.

Comment: Or use transactions: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/tdb_transactions.html